# Could not read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I know this question has been asked a number of times but for some reason I can't solve it.

I am 100% sure that there is no problem in the column name.

This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (category_id INTEGER, category_name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(category_id))
```

This is the access to the column.
As can be seen I do a small test first to make sure I have the correct column name.
Using the name I print to the LogCat the value of the column in the first row.
It works perfectly. Yet, when passed to the adapter I get the above error.

```
    Cursor mGroupsCursor = _dbHelper.fetchGroup();
getActivity().startManagingCursor(mGroupsCursor);
mGroupsCursor.moveToFirst();

String colName = "category_name";
Log.d("ToratYavneh", "i = " + i + "   category_name = " + mGroupsCursor.getString(mGroupsCursor.getColumnIndex(colName)));

ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

MyExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, getActivity(),
    R.layout.rowlayout_category,                     // Your row layout for a group
    R.layout.rowlayout_sub_category,                 // Your row layout for a child
    new String[] { colName },                      // Field(s) to use from group cursor
    new int[] {R.id.category_name },                 // Widget ids to put group data into
    new String[] { "sub_category_name" },           // Field(s) to use from child cursors
    new int[] { R.id.sub_category_name });          // Widget ids to put child data into

elv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I thought that maybe the problem was in the child but it never reaches getChildrenCursor.

Here is the code for the cursor:

```
    public Cursor fetchGroup() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    return _database.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Comment: can you post code for this _dbHelper.fetchGroup() ?

Comment: its seems like that you are try to get value from cursor that is not in cursor i have also face same error many times show your query

Comment: yeah try performaing complete uninstall and install of your app, see if it gets resolved,, by looking at you code its clear its not name or cursor not initialized issue, issue might be with database creation.

Comment: Tried that to no avail.

Comment: Your cursor doesn't seem to have a column with name `sub_category_name`.

Comment: @laalto sub_category_name is in the child table: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sub_categories (sub_category_id INTEGER, category_id INTEGER, sub_category_name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(sub_category_id))

Comment: Yes and it's not in the cursor.

Comment: It's not even reaching the getChildrenCursor method. That is where the child cursor is used.